# OAuth library for BlackBerry apps (for a twitter client)

Tags: blackberry, oauth, twitter

Is there an OAuth library available for integration with BlackBerry apps? I would like to post a tweet from my app but could not find anything which would help in logging in.

Did find [this URL](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=648) but could not get it working in my BB app.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: How can i use sign-post library in blackberry. It includes some libraries that not supported by blackberry java. please help me? please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723479/google-data-api-library-for-blackberry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

Comment: How can i use sign-post library in blackberry. It includes some libraries that not supported by blackberry java. please help me?