# Verifying Twitter OAuth on BlackBerry

Tags: java, web-services, blackberry, oauth

Hey all, i want to integrate my Blackberry App with Twitter, and found that the way to do it is with OAuth. The problem I have is that i would like to do the verification of this from my server as to put less strain on the device, but I have no idea how to get the OAuth PIN from the server to be displayed on the device so the user can enter it, any ideas as to how i can do this? or an alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. OAuth was designed such that only the service provider can provide authentication (so that the developers don't have to store their client passwords on their database servers and if the client changes their passwords, then it would have to be managed also on the developers side too). There is only one source of authentication and that's from the service provider (Twitter, in this case). Sharing of passwords is therefore eliminated.

OAuth doesn't work on PINs but rather using Request/Access Token. Follow the [Beginners' Guide to OAuth](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/) and [Twitter Developer's Auth Page](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) to see how you can incorporate OAuth to Twitter. Just to give you an heads up, you will have to [register](http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) your application to Twitter.

---

**Update** For Mobile and Desktop applications, rather go through Twitter's **xAuth**. [Here's](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) a documentation on how to register and use your application to use xAuth.

- [Twitter OAuth FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq).

Comment: My application is registered and the twitter OAuth does give a PIN in return after prompting the Allow/Deny page. So there's no way I can authenticate from a blackberry? or rather from the server and redirect to the blackberry? Because de UberTwiter client asks for my Username and Password and automatically generated the authorization on my Twitter page, any idea how they manage?

Comment: Guess i'll have to request Twitter for permission to use XAuth it seems, thanks for the clearing my mind :)

Comment: They are using Basic Http Authorization, but that's deprecated. To use OAuth, you have to write your application to follow the OAuth protocol. Alternatively, use an OAuth Library written in Java.

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594850/oauth-library-for-blackberry-apps-for-a-twitter-client

Comment: I can't use OAuth, if it's as you say i have to use XAuth since OAuth requires the user to be prompted and allow the App access to the account, this is not possible for me considerong my architecture, the user requests from a BB device and it's the server who handles the authorization. So for this i would have to use XAuth which does not prompt the user

Comment: Once you're happy, don't forget to vote the anser that best worked for you.

Comment: Would, but i don't have enough rep to do it :P thx for the help :)